# progressBar not updating with setProgress

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am trying to process some files and it takes some time, so I would like to use a progressBar while the operation is being performed. In my activity, I have a button which starts the processing, when I press on it, the progressBar does not update and after a while the operation is complete and I see the result of the processing (so the function is properly called and act as expected).

The progressBar is visible, it just does not update. I have displayed `getProgress()` in the log and the value increases, only the actual progressBar does not update.

The function which should update the progressBar:

```
private byte[] processFiles() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        //Init things
        final ArrayList<String> fileNames = getFileList();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setMax(fileNames.size());
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);

        for (int i = 0 ; i<fileNames.size(); i++) {
            //Do stuff on files
            progressBar.setProgress(i+1);
            Log.d("CurrentActivity", String.valueOf(progressBar.getProgress()));
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
```

In the `onCreate()`:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
```

I have also tried as displayed in the [android developer tutorial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) using a Thread but with no success (though I did not use a while loop but a for loop, but figured it shouldn't matter).

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Note I have also tried to use this before each update as suggested in some other answers:

```
progressBar.setProgress(0);
progressBar.setMax(fileNames.size());
```

Edit, here is my onClickListener:

```
fileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Init things
            try{
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            outStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
                            outStream.write(processFiles());
                            outStream.close();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //stuff that updates ui

                                }
                            });
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now the progressBar works but using processedFile fails, it is an image that I display with Glide, it worked well before but now it doesn't display anything.

Edit 2: using `runOnUiThread` for all UI update worked like a charm and fixed my new issue.

Comment: on which thread you doo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two threads:

**Main Thread (aka UI Thread) (aka WhereYouWorkAlways Thread)**

Find and store the `ProgressBar`, create a `Handler` and then create the new Thread (see below)

**Work Thread (aka just a new thread)**

Inside the Thread Runnable, after each step of the work (= after each file operation is done) post a `Runnable` at the handler which updates the progress bar

```
handler.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        progressBar.setProgress(i);
    }
})
```

**Why two Threads are needed**

The main thread is actually the UI Thread which means that every operations is placed in the "Update" step of the following cycle:

```
-> Update -> (Re)Draw -> Wait ->
```

Which means that if the Update lasts 10s then the screen will update after 10s. (Most UIs are single thread based)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Is it possible to update the progressBar without using two threads? Why does my method not work?

Comment: Updated answer including your question

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, I will try your suggestions.

Comment: The new thread should be created in my `onCreate()` function?

Comment: When you want to start the operation

Comment: I have updated my question, now the progressBar works but the result from my processing does not work anymore. How can I get it?

Comment: You can move all the `outStream` operations inside the Thread

Comment: I moved all the outstream things inside the thread and then used the `runOnUiThread` to display things and it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because on each iteration of cycle you have `progressBar.setProgress(0);`

Comment: It was a suggestion by some other poster having the same problem, I also update it to the correct value after anyway, so it should not matter.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't seen `setProgress(i+1);`